# VB 2010 how to save value in label to txt file then have the values reappear in the corresponding labels when an event triggers

Tags: file, label, vb.net-2010

Basically, I have a file called "accounts.txt" in this, there is a list of accounts registered on the game.

I then have after you click BtnLogin, a groupbox appear that has values that can be changed through a text box appear in labels each LblSP LblHP LblBrawn and the text box is TxtBrain.

I want each of these values that appear after you input TxtBrain, including the one in TxtBrain to save into the accounts.txt file with the corresponding user logged in. And when that user logs in again, have these values reappear in the same places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try saving your accounts and the corresponding information in a comma delimited fashion in accounts.txt.  Have each account be separated by a new line.

So your accounts.txt might end up like this:

Account1, valBrain, valSP, valHP, valBrawn
Account2, valBrain1, valSP1, valHP1, valBrawn1
Account3, valBrain2, valSP2, valHP2, valBrawn2

Your program could define a struct or class that would correspond to these values and you could load each record's value into the class and add it to a list.
Then you loop through the list to find your account and get it's corresponding data.